# Git - commits and push of same repository from two different machines with differing folders

Tags: git

I have the following folder structure:

```
AllMyWork/
  --.git/
  --Proj1/
     file1.cpp, ..., file10.cpp
  --WindowsOnly/ (this subfolder does not exist on Linux machine)
     filea.bat
  --LinuxOnly/ (this subfolder does not exist on Windows machine)
     fileb.sh
```

I alternate between working on `Proj1` from a Windows machine and a Linux machine. Both machines share the exact same files/folder structure in terms of `.git/` and `Proj1/` and its contents `file1.cpp` through `file10.cpp`. What they don't share however are subfolders `WindowsOnly/` and the associated file `filea.bat` (this is only available on the Windows machine) and subfolders `LinuxOnly/` and the associated file `fileb.sh` (this is only available on the Linux machine).

Now, I did a commit / push from the Windows machine. When I open the Linux machine and issue command `git status`, I obtain:

`deleted:    WindowsOnly/filea.bat`

This is understandable since Git thinks that this file was deleted since that folder does not exist on the Linux machine.

However, what happens now if I work on the common files in the `Proj1` and commit / push from the Linux machine? The next time I open the Windows machine, would the subfolder `WindowsOnly/` and `filea.bat` get deleted from the Windows machine since the most recent push from the Linux machine did not include those files?

ETA: How both the Windows machine and the Linux machine got to share the same `.git/` and `Proj1/` folder is that on each machine, I run GoogleDrive/Insync that automatically syncs these folders. On the Linux machine, I specifically instruct GoogleDrive/Insync not to download and sync `WindowsOnly/` and on the Windows machine, I specifically instruct GoogleDrive/Insync not to download and sync `LinuxOnly/`.

Comment: You would have to commit the deletion for the files to be removed upon pull.

Comment: I usually suggest the first chapter of Pro Git to better understand these concepts; https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control.

Comment: @Adam, it appears that from the Linux machine I am going to constantly see these files as being deleted and I should be careful not to commit their deletion. The other alternative is to replicate needlessly both folders `WindowsOnly/` and `LinuxOnly/` on both machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say needlessly. You need those files to support the project on both platforms. It's not like linux (the kernel project) has different branches/repos to support the number of architectures they support. It's a single project with all the architectures in a single plate.

Just in case, in order to pull this off, what I would do is have a common branch (say, `main`) with `Proj1`, then a `windows` branch and a `linux` branch both created from `main`. The windows branch is where you hack `WindowsOnly` stuff (that's the only branch where that directory is held) and then in `linux` branch you hold `LinuxOnly`.

You could even go as far as create `linux` branch from `windows` branch (or viceversa) (making sure to delete the files from the other architecture) just so that git can see the relation between the files (if there's any). That might ease a little bit stuff when you want to cherry-pick changes from one architecture to the other, but you are kind of going into deeper waters if you want to try this trick (it's doable.... but you need to have a higher **git-zen** level to understand why git will complain one way or the other when trying to move around stuff between the two architecture branches).

Comment: I was doing some research to see if .gitignore allows for conditions (like a .vimrc does), but that seems not possible. That could have been a way out by doing a query on the OS somehow. In your suggestion, whenever I work on the linux/windows machine, I suppose I would work on one branch that does not "see" the other branch. I will try that out. I agree with you that I could have been more careful about using the word *needlessly*. These files are not too big. To maintain consistency and ease of use (to avoid branches), it is possibly prudent to have the exact same folders on each platform.

Comment: If you do go down the path of using `linux` and `windows` branches, when you switch to each one of those two branches, you won't see the files from the other architecture. They way I see it, if you go back to `main`, you would not see any of the files of either architecture, just `Proj1`.

Comment: If it were me I would just have everything everywhere and not bother trying to filter out different things in specific branches. In large repos and large teams, there will be hundreds or even thousands of projects and folders that everyone has a copy of in their local repo, even though they only focus on a small number that they work on. As long as drive space isn't an issue, it's normal to have large portions of the repo "needlessly" on every machine with a copy of the repo. ;)

Comment: @TTT It's also useful, sometimes, to see how something is done on "the other system". Is the behavior on your OS a bug? Well, if the Windows version behaves different *and there's a comment that says "still need to fix the linux version" there*, and your Linux version behavior seems wrong, now you can be pretty sure it *is* wrong.  (though, like the man with two watches, you're never *sure* what time it is...)